# Blue-Green Deployment: how to synchronize and maintain data consistency after migration?

Tags: microservices, deployment, load-balancing

To provide zero downtime upgrades of my highload service I use blue green deployment strategy.

Every moment data changing happens, so how to migrate all data consistently? In the moment I switch between blue and green the data is changing.

What is the best strategy to maintain data consistency (as much as possible)?

Comment: This question is quite vague. Usually the solution to this is to blue-green stateless resources and have shared, separate state.

Comment: Does it mean blue-green strategy is not appropriate for this case?